# Slicing columns in Python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am new in Python. I want to **slice columns from index 1 to end of a marix** and perform some operations on the those sliced out columns. Following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_df = pd.read_csv('train_475_60_W1.csv',header = None) 
train = train_df.as_matrix()
y = train[:,0]
X = train[:,1:-1]
```

The problem is if I execeute "train.shape", it gives me (89512, **61**). But when I execute "X.shape", it give me (89512, **59**). I was expecting to get **60** as I want to execute operations on all the colunms except the first one. Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: don't you want `X = train[:,1:]`? with slicing here the end slice isn't included which is not what you want

Comment: "From index 1 to end of a matrix" is `train[:,1:]`, not `train[:,1:-1]`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks! That's the info I was missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
X = train[:,1:-1]
```

you cut off the last column. -1 refers to the last column, and Python includes the beginning but not the end of a slice - so `lst[2:6]` would give you entries 2,3,4, and 5. Correct it to

```
X = train[:,1:]
```

BTW, you can make your code format properly by including four spaces before each line (you can just highlight it and hit Ctrl+K).

Comment: Thanks...for both the suggestions! It's working now!

Answer (score 3):

The thing you should know with slicing for single dimension even in normal lists is that it looks like this:

```
[start : end]
```

with start `included` and end `excluded`.

you can also use these:

```
[:x] # from the start to x
[x:] # from x to the end
```

you can then generalize than to 2D or more, so in your case it would be:

```
X = train[:,1:] # the first : to get all rows, and 1: to get all columns except the first
```

you can learn more about these in [here](https://www.datacamp.com/) if you want, it's a good way to practice

Comment: Thanks...I didn't know that Python doesn't include the last column in slicing! It's working Great! Thanks for the tutorial link!!

Comment: No problem at all, don't forget to accept the answer that suited you most as a sign for future users who might see this question ;) @SumaiyaIqbal